# How to clean data more efficiently using df.apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm a beginner of Python Pandas. I got a dataframe to clean up. And one of the tasks is to clean the brackets from certain countries. `Bolivia (Plurinational State of)` to `Bolivia`.

DataFrame (df)

```
Country Energy Supply   Energy Supply per capita    % Renewable
178 Saudi Arabia    7985    264000000   0.000352
```

What I did is

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].apply(lambda x: x.split(" (")[0])
```

But it's quite repetitive and I think there will be an easier way to achieve the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a slightly bigger example of your data so we can easily test and do some profiling to see what's faster?

Comment: Your code is fine unless what you consider repetitive is the same action for brackets, and then for slashs, dashs, pounds, etc.

Comment: You can use vectorised `str.split` for this: `df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.split(' (').str[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps.